# Places Type Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to return the places near some points I have, and I want to know if it's possible to filter the results inside the callback function. I have this code:

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({ //pentru fiecare farmacie
            location:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            radius: 500,
            type: ['pharmacy', 'restaurant', 'school']
            },function callBack(results, status){       
                markersP= []; 
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        createMarker(results[i]); //here's where markersP are populated
                    }   
                    if( markersP.length !=0){
                        for(var i=0; i < markersP.length; ++i){
                            queue.add(imob, markersP[i].getPosition(), 'pharmacy');
                        }
                    }                   
                }

            });
```

Basically, I want to know if I can filter for each type in the callback function. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to know if you can filter in the service call, or in the callback?

Comment: In the callback function, sorry

Comment: I think `type: ['pharmacy', 'restaurant', 'school']` is not allowed, according to the documentation you can pass only one value of type string: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#PlaceSearchRequest